# Catching only *one* KeyboardInterruptException

Tags: python, unix, exception, keyboardinterrupt

I have a long-running task that may be interrupted because an exception is raised inside it, or because <kbd>Control+C</kbd> is pressed signaling a `SIGINT`, raising a `KeyboardInterruptException`.

In both of these cases, the path to follow is to store the results that are already processed by the task, to prevent the lose of the computing time. This store takes some time, as it may need to process a good amount of information. The problem appears when <kbd>Control+C</kbd> is pressed *again* when the interrupt has already been caught.

Example:

```py
task = SomeTask()
try:
    task.start()
except KeyboardInterruptException:
    print("Keyboard interrupted")
except Exception as e:
    print_exception(e) # To show what happened
finally:
    task.store_results() # If Control-C is pressed here, data gets corrupted
```

I need a way to catch the interrupt, launch the store process *and* prevent another interrupt from happening.

Comment: Suggest you add and OS tag to your question—because handling `SIGINT` varies depending on what operating system you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the signal handler:

```
import signal

task = SomeTask()
try:
    task.start()
except KeyboardInterruptException:
    print("Keyboard interrupted")
except Exception as e:
    print_exception(e) # To show what happened
finally:
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lamda *_: print('Wait!'))
    task.store_results() # If Control-C is pressed here, data gets corrupted
```

Source: https://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/handle-ctrlc-in-your-script/

Comment: This did the trick for me. It has less side effects because the first time it enters through the try/except and then it disables the interrupt :) Thanks